# Problems loging in gnome-session after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, lightdm

I just upgraded from ubuntu 12.02 LTS to 14.04 LTS. After a miriad of problems which i was able to solve one by one, the upgrade was successful. It was however impossible to log in the default gnome session ( I could still log in on a xbmc session ).

After some research i found out that unity-2d was no longer delivered on this upgrade. Knowing that my Laptop has one of those crappy sis671 chips, i decided  then to install the ubuntu-session, and gnome-session-fallback. But i still cant log in any one of those new sessions that  i did install.

Checking my .xsession-errors i found two possible causes. The first was a python script complaining about the non existence of the gconf module. After installing that module, that problem was solved. The second was this error: "init: Failed to obtain gnome-session instance: Unknown parameter: XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP". A google search on the topic wasn't very helpfull.

Any help or idea is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add X-LightDM-DesktopName=GNOME to the GNOME session .desktop file. That file should be located in:

```
/usr/share/xsessions/
```

Comment: Than you for the quick answer, but i had already looked into that. All the .desktop file have an entry " X-LightDM-DesktopName=..." ont the gnome.desktop it is ..=GNOME , on the ubuntu.desktop and gnome-fallback.desktop it is ..=Unity. Even after chaning them all to ..=GNOME the login process gets stuck rifht after entering password. The only  .desktop file that has no reference to X-LightDM-DesktopName is the xbmc.desktop, but was expected as they are not related.

Comment: Are you sure you are using LightDM? You can find out by executing this: cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager

Comment: yes, my DM is /usr/sbin/lightdm. Also any changes i make omn its config file reflects ont the greeter screen.

Answer (score -1):

From what i've learned from [Unity can't be started from kdm](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1293629) bug on lounchpad the problem seem  to be that the enviroment variable  XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP was not set. After setting it on /etc/profile the problem was solved.